# how to convert string from ascii to hexadecimal in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert string from ascii to hexadecimal

I tried:

```
var stringing = "";
jQuery.each("SomeText".split(""), function (i, data) {
    stringing = stringing + data.charCodeAt(0)
});
```

But this output is not the same as what I get at
http://www.asciitohex.com/

I need to get the same values because only that works in KQL in sharepoint

Comment: I tried this var something="text";
console.log(something.toString(16)), but it didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
String.prototype.convertToHex = function (delim) {
    return this.split("").map(function(c) {
        return ("0" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(delim || "");
};
```

and

```
"SomeText".convertToHex();
// -> "536f6d6554657874"

"SomeText".convertToHex(" ");
// -> "53 6f 6d 65 54 65 78 74"
```

Note that this **will fail** with Unicode characters. Use it for ASCII/ANSI input only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Buffer**  to convert ascii to hex

```
let hex = Buffer('Some Text', 'ascii').toString('hex');
console.log(hex);
```

Comment: There's no support for `Buffer` on browser-based JavaScript. If you try to run your code on browser's console, it will fail. Though original question didn't explicitly ask for browser or server based JS, having "jquery" on it _may_ suggest that the solution was looking for, should work in a web browser. You should specify in your answer that this only will work on node.js to prevent confusion.